# Unity error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to `int' but it's bool

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I have error

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type bool to int.

My declaration:

```
public bool isBig = false;
```

If statement with error:

```
if (player.GetHP() < 6 && player.isBig == false)
```

I don't understand this. I have also change this bool to return and checked few solutions:

```
player.GetBig() == false/0 / (player.GetBig()) == false/0 / !(player.GetBig())
```

but nothing works...

// Edit

```
public int GetBig()
    { // isBig is bool
        return this.isBig;
    }

public int GetHP()
{ // HP is int
    return this.HP;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the exception is thrown inside GetHP()? GetHP returns int but code tries to return a bool?

Comment: @Frode if (player.GetHP() < 6) works ok. My return in GetBig() return this.isBig; and return in GetHP: return this.HP; (HP is int)

Comment: `public int GetBig() {// isBig is bool`???

Comment: Also, for completeness, trying to do `if(bool && int)` or `if(bool < int)` will not throw exception _Cannot implicitly convert type_. Instead it will throw _Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'_

Comment: Sorry guys and thanks. I'm so tired. Beginner typo - copy-paste...

Answer (score 5):

Simple typo.

```
 public int GetBig()
```

should be

```
public bool GetBig()
```

Comment: Good catch, but the author stated that the line with exception was: `if (player.GetHP() < 6 && player.isBig == false)`. But probably this solves the issue.

Comment: isBig could not be 1 or 0 as this is not C but C# ;) You cannot implicity convert int to bool in C# and the value of isBig would never be 0 or 1. But almost for 100% your answer solves the problem, but in the question the problem was difrent.

Comment: And that was exactly what the error said. ;-)